# Free space in MySQL after deleting tables & columns?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database of around 20GB. I need to delete 5 tables & drop a few columns in some other 3 tables.

Dropping 5 tables with free some 3 GB and dropping columns in other tables should free another 8GB.

How do I reclaim this space from MySQL.

I've read dumping the database and restoring it back as one of the solution but I'm not really sure how that works, I am not even sure if this only works for deleting the entire database or just parts of it?

Please suggest how to go about this. THanks.

Comment: @Gaurav - once table dropped, mysql will remove the physical file as well, logically, disk space is free. what is your problem/intention ?

Comment: I don't think thats the case because I dropped a table of 1 GB and I am pretty sure I don't have the disk space back? Even if I did, how would you go around this for dropping columns?

Comment: @Gaurav - Did you do `du -shc YOUR_DATABASE_DIRECTORY` before and after ? You can use `optimize table` for dropping column although mysql again will auto handle for clearing space for table schema update

Comment: @ajreal: maybe Gaurav isn't using MyISAM tables?  InnoDB tables are all on a single file/block device

Comment: Not really. To be honest I am not even sure what that means?By Database directory do you mean where the tables are actually stored?

Comment: If you have a quick minute can you join the sql chat room?

Comment: @Gaurav - On dear, memory space or disk space ? had you tried **flush table** after the dropping?

Comment: @ajreal: yeah I am using InnoDB tables

Comment: @Javier: Any ideas about InnoDB. I read that there is a way of having one file per table?

Comment: Since you are using InnoDB, are you using innodb_file_per_table? If not, you won't get the space back because it's in the shared tablespace. InnoDB will reuse it eventually, but you won't get it back right away.

Comment: No I am not. Is it possible to set innodb_file_per_table now?

Comment: No. You need to set it up that way to begin with, or else set up a new DB that way and import all of your data.

Comment: value: 'OFF' as suspected. Can i turn this on and then reclaim the space or is it too late?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you're using InnoDB without the file per table option.

Reclaiming space from the innodb tablespace is not generally possible in this mode. Your only course of action is to dump the whole database, turn on file-per-table mode, and reload it (with a completely clean mysql instance). This is going to take a long time with a large database; mk-parallel-dump and restore tools might be a bit quicker, but it will still take a while. Be sure to test this process on a non-production server first.

Comment: Once the option is turned on, any new tables will get a file. This means you can turn it on and slowly move one table at a time into it's own file (though dumping/reloading the table) until you're done. This will let you split downtime into many smaller periods instead of one large one, if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: Doesn't apply without file_per_table, Mark is right there.**

What's going on is that once MySQL takes space, it won't give it back. This is so that if you delete 500 rows and then immediately insert 500, it doesn't have to give that space back to the file system and then request it back. It's an optimization to avoid filesystem overhead, and it works well when you delete little bits.

If you delete a large amount, it will take a long time to end up using all that space again, which can be annoying. This can be fixed two ways: dropping the table and reloading the contents, or optimizing the table (which I believe basically reloads the table internally).

All you have to do to get space back from a table is:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE my_big_table;
```

Note that this can take a while, it's not a near instant operation. Basically, plan for a some downtime. If your tables are just a few gigs, it shouldn't be too long (probably a few minutes). This also rebuilds the indexes and does some other housekeeping.

You can see more about optimize [on the MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html). Here is it's advice:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE should be used if you have deleted a large part of a table or if you have made many changes to a table with variable-length rows (tables that have VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB, or TEXT columns). Deleted rows are maintained in a linked list and subsequent INSERT operations reuse old row positions. You can use OPTIMIZE TABLE to reclaim the unused space and to defragment the data file.

Comment: "If your tables are just a few gigs," If by gigs you mean "Gigas", your phrase doesn't seems really accurate. It took me 52min to optimize every tables of a database of 4Go :) Just saying that for further visitors.

Comment: Mysql does a full rewrite internally. Please also note that the disk space of the "real size" of the table needs to be available when running `OPTIMIZE TABLE [table]`

Comment: I've got: 
> Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
.It ran for 40 secs for a 150mb table.