# Clearing MySQL disk space

Tags: mysql, flush, disk, diskspace

We had a very large MySQL table (about 100GB in size) that we deleted.
The disk space doesn't seem to have been freed; how do you cause MySQL to flush its changes to disk?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4340899/1726343

Comment: Check this answer: **[Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)**

Answer (score 0):

look in your my.ini for the data dir, all the files for that datbase are in a sub directory of the data dir, just delete those if any still remain.

Comment: No, that is not always correct, not for InnoDB engine.