# mysql bulk drop tables where table_name like '%phrase'

Tags: mysql, sql

OK I have about 68,000 tables i need to drop with a particular phrase. When I run the command:

SHOW TABLES where table_name like '%phrase';

I get all the results i need, but I tried to run the following code and It only got rid of like 6 out of 68,000:

```
SET @temp_statement = NULL;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.`', table_name, '`') INTO @temp_statement 
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    table_schema, table_name
  FROM
    information_schema.tables 
  WHERE
    table_schema = 'db_name_goes_here' AND table_name LIKE 'table_base_name_here_%'
  LIMIT 10 -- a limit to avoid exceeding group_concat_max_len
  ) JUST_A_TEMP_NAME;

-- up to this point, @temp_statement holds something like this:
-- mydb.`table1`,mydb.`table2`,...,mydb.`tableN`

SET @temp_statement = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @temp_statement);
SELECT @temp_statement; -- let's see the SQL statement before executing it
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @temp_statement;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SET @temp_statement = NULL; -- clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps:

First execute:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') statement
FROM   information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_schema = 'db_name_goes_here'
AND    table_name LIKE 'table_base_name_here_%';
```

The output will look like:

```
statement
--------------------------------------------------------
DROP myschema.mytable1;
DROP myschema.mytable2;
```

Then take the output, and execute that again as a batch of SQL statements.

Seems to me the most pragmatic way to approach this.

Comment: Ok- that seems reasonable and direct. My second follow up question: ive noticed that when i drop tables, the dropped tables are being stored somewhere. SO when i delete 1gb of tables- they are taking up another gb of space. How can i stop this and get back all the 'dropped table' storage space.

Comment: That is a whole other question. You may find answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338645/free-space-in-mysql-after-deleting-tables-columns).